# POST request with file, data, auth, headers

Tags: python, post, base64

I want to create a POST request that sends data and a file to a web site. There is a password and a username that is required, also a action header. The file needs to be base64 encoded. All data needs to be JSON encoded. This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

url = 'web.site'
username = 'user123'
password = 'pw123'
city = 'London'
countrycode = 'GB'
with open("file.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
    string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
headers = {'action':'createOrder'}

data = {'city':city, 'countrycode':countrycode, 'file':file}

r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password),
                  headers=headers,
                  json=data)
```

I should receive an order number in return. If I do ask for the status_code I receive "403" though.

What do I need to change to get a working request?

Comment: What makes you think that username/password is valid?

Comment: Are you 100% sure about username and password?

Comment: Usually it takes more than just a post request like you've tried. Probably you must also add some cookies and other headers to the request. Try to inspect the entire upload process in your browser's network tab and then replicate it.

Comment: Username and password are correct, already checked it too many times.

Comment: So I need to put all headers I see in the tab? I will try it.

Comment: are you sure it is a basic auth? just in case check different auth types: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: from where did you get the file value in data = {'city':city, 'countrycode':countrycode, 'file':file} ... it seems it is not defined .... put string instead of file and check if it works again